# Spring Data Jpa Repository findBy Part of Data not by doing all cases

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, repository

I cannot find similar question, so I post this question.
I'm pleased to be linked similar question I have.

My Spring server get some parts of 3 Data from UI client and will give appropriate data to UI client found in DB.
I have to identify and execute respectively findby~ function for it.

In ProjectService

```
public List<Project> getProjectsByPartialData(ProjectDto projectDto) {
    if (projectDto.getYearCodeName()!= null && projectDto.getCustomerCoName() != null && projectDto.getSeasonCodeName()!=null) {
        return projectRepository.findByYearCodeNameAndCustomerCoNameAndSeasonCodeName(projectDto.getYearCodeName(),projectDto.getCustomerCoName(),projectDto.getSeasonCodeName());
    } else if (projectDto.getYearCodeName() == null && projectDto.getCustomerCoName() != null && projectDto.getSeasonCodeName()!=null) {
        return projectRepository.findByCustomerCoNameAndSeasonCodeName(projectDto.getCustomerCoName(),projectDto.getSeasonCodeName());
    } else if (projectDto.getYearCodeName()!= null && projectDto.getCustomerCoName() == null && projectDto.getSeasonCodeName()!=null) {
        return projectRepository.findByYearCodeNameAndSeasonCodeName(projectDto.getYearCodeName(),projectDto.getSeasonCodeName());
    } else if (projectDto.getYearCodeName()!= null && projectDto.getCustomerCoName() != null && projectDto.getSeasonCodeName()==null) {
        return projectRepository.findByYearCodeNameAndCustomerCoName(projectDto.getYearCodeName(),projectDto.getCustomerCoName());
    } ...3 more to go
}
```

Is there any simple way to do this??

---

extra

In Project

```
@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "YEAR_CODE", referencedColumnName = "CODE")
    private YearCode yearCode;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_CO_CODE", referencedColumnName = "CODE")
    private CustomerCo customerCo;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SEASON_CODE", referencedColumnName = "CODE")
    private SeasonCode seasonCode;

    ... other properties
}
```

In ProjectDto

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class ProjectDto {

    private String yearCodeName;

    @JsonProperty(value = "customerNameCode")
    private String customerCoName;

    private String seasonCodeName;
    ... other properties
}
```

Comment: You can prefer JPA specification for this problem. Hope it may helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use `findBy...` method for each case. Spring Data has special `Specification` interface to define reusable predicate. Just implement `toPredicate(..)` method from this interface and use your implementation as a parameter in repository method:

```
List<Project> findAll(Specification spec);
```

See more:

[Spring Data Specifications and Querydsl](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/)

[REST Query Language with Spring Data JPA Specifications](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications)